# I am not able to migrate the files from my django app to AWS RDS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

```
py manage.py makemigrations
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py:143: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "database-1.cf9dt6lrnclf.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.42.207), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

  warnings.warn()
```

I tried to edit the inbound rules in my Security Group, but still could not migrate.

Comment: "connection to server at "database-1.cf9dt6lrnclf.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.42.207), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out" This generally means security group(s) on the RDS server don't allow the outgoing IPs from the django instance.  Disallowed traffic will be dropped which looks like a connection timeout.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question to answer all of the following clarification questions: 1. Are you running this Django app in the same VPC as the RDS instance, on an EC2 server or something? Or are you running it from your local computer? 2. What are the specific security group rules attached to your RDS instance? 3. If you are running this from your local computer, is the RDS instance configured to be publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0):

> ... server at "database-1.cf9dt6lrnclf.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.42.207)

That's an
[unroutable](https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters)
IP address, within the 172.16.0.0/12 prefix.

You didn't specify where client and server were.
But if the public Internet cloud is between them,
it's hardly surprising that those routers didn't
convey your IP packets to an unroutable address.
It is only for private use, within the AWS infrastructure.